# Mobile application development using HTML5

Tags: html, mobile

Is there any way to develop and mobile application using HTML5 **without using any tool**. I know this is very basic question. But I have spend more than 2 hours on this. But all links says to use some external tool.

**Why I didn't want any tool for this?**

1. I want to know complete architecture of HTML5 based mobile application.
2. If I have ability to develop mobile app without using any tool then I can manage all tools easily

Comment: Can you give examples of what you consider to be "external tools"?

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) , [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/complete/evaluate) , etc.., friend

Comment: As @altafhussain mentions below, these aren't really tools, they're frameworks. You can develop a HTML5 app but then you will still need a kind of shell around it to make it look like a native phone app. Therefore it makes more sense to start building on top of the framework from the very beginning, it saves you having to modify stuff afterwards.

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra Thank you friend. I will try to develop using phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is basically for webpages and hence HTML5. Yes you can create a mobile app with HTML5 only, but it will be a like a website and when you want to display it, you will still need to use webview or a browser, so still you will need some other tools.

But there are some frameworks which are using HTML 5, try PhoneGap.

Hope this will help.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create a mobile app with HTML5 because it is an accessible and affordable technology for mobile app development. HTML5 is a productive and stable technology that offers a streamlined framework to develop a mobile app. The HTML5 mobile app development framework toolkits are helpful in creating cost-effective web apps.

The toolkit includes Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) used for formatting the, Yes you can create a mobile app with HTML5  Because, HTML pages for an attractive user interface. CSS separately stores the information related to fonts, colors, backgrounds, styles, positions of header and footer to be applied to HTML components. So, an HTML5 toolkit has libraries of Cascading Style Sheets that developers can utilize while developing HTML web pages.

Hope this information will help.

Thanks